# Trying to use switch-case with actionlistener

Tags: java

I was wondering if there is any way I could use the switch statement with actionListener instead of if-else statements.

**I tried two things:**

**1) Tried to use ae.getSource() as the switch**

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
{
    switch(ae.getSource())
    {
       case b1:
           //statement
           break;
    }
}
```

I figured out this obviously doesn't work since ae.getSource() will return the object

**2)Tried converting the ae.getSource() value to String**

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
{
    String src = ae.getSource().toString();
        switch(src)
        {
            case "b1":
                //statement
                break;
        }
}
```

which also doesn't work but I though it was worth a shot. So is there any way I can make this work or I should just rely on the trusty If-Else.

Comment: Show the if/else version.

Comment: @shmosel the if/else version is the standard one where I just use if (ae.getSource==b1)

Comment: You can't switch on `Object`. What does `toString()` return?

Comment: @shmosel it returns this " javax.swing.JButton[,72,30,56x26,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.5,border=javax.swing.plaf.BorderUIResource$CompoundBorderUIResource@4d52d718,flags=296,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,defaultIcon=,disabledIcon=,disabledSelectedIcon=,margin=javax.swing.plaf.InsetsUIResource[top=2,left=14,bottom=2,right=14],paintBorder=true,paintFocus=true,pressedIcon=,rolloverEnabled=true,rolloverIcon=,rolloverSelectedIcon=,selectedIcon=,text=Add,defaultCapable=true] " didn't expect that haha.

Comment: I guess you'll have to stick with the if/else.

Comment: You can `switch` on `Object`s, but for this your `b1` has to be `final`...

Comment: You can also use `actionCommand` property, if you want to use `String˙s...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use it like this(because it worked for me)

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
{
    switch(ae.getActionCommand())
    {
       case "b1":
           //statement
           break;
    }
}
```